# How to customize or prevent community user from seeing default 'URL No Longer Exists' page

Tags: visualforce, community, customer-community, redirect

I am developing community. We have customized all VF pages with html/css.
I have custom login page, and to prevent user from seeing default login page, I have created URL redirect from '/login' to '/Login'.
And one more redirect from '/' to '/apex/MyMessages'.

But when user types 'mycommunity.force.com/blablabla' he sees default 'URL No Longer Exists' page. 
How can I prevent it or customize this page?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: This looks relevant to this question: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l5Y7AAI

Comment: @DavidJ no,  it seems not possible until they implement that idea